# Which metrics is used in the *training* of XGBoost : is it the one in the so-called parameter "eval_metric"?

Tags: xgboost

In XGBoost, when calling the train function, I can provide multiple metrics, for example : 'eval_metric':['auc','logloss']

Which ones are used in the training and how to state it technically in the tool ?

(This is counter-intuitive to me that several metrics could be used simultaneously)

```
hyperparameters_xgboost = {'validate_parameters':False,'eval_metric':['auc','logloss'],'max_depth' : 3,'eta':0.3,'objective'  :'binary:logistic','tree_method': 'hist'}


bst=xgb.train(hyperparameters_xgboost,dmatrix_train,num_round,evals=list_evals,early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name indicates, the values for `eval_metric` are used as the metrics when evaluating the model's performance on data passed using `eval_set` (see also [this example from the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.evals_result)). The loss that is actually used when training the gradient boosted trees can be specified using the `objective` keyword when using the `scikit-learn` API, which by default is [a squared error loss for the regressor](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) and [a logistic loss for the classifier](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier).